# R Highcharter: Formatting dual y-Axis chart

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I have a column & line chart, using primary and secondary y-axis. I am wondering how I can format each axis separately.

I want to be able to do 2 things:

- Have the primary axis maximum be set at 100
- Be able to use `colorByPoint` for the column series. Currently when I use the parameter, the line series does not appear.

Below is my dataset:

```
> dput(SiteOTD)
structure(list(SBU = c("LS", "LS", "LS", "INT", "LS", "APS", 
"LS", "CS", "INT", "CS", "SIS", "CS", "APS", "ES", "ASG", "CS", 
"INT", "ASG", "ES", "ES", "APS", "CS", "SIS", "CS", "CS", "SIS", 
"APS", "CS", "CS", "ASG", "ASG", "CS", "ES", "CS", "SIS", "ASG", 
"APS", "ASG", "CS", "SIS", "CS", "SIS", "APS", "CS", "ES", "LS"
), Region = c("IATA III", "IATA I", "IATA I", "IATA I", "IATA III", 
"IATA I", "IATA II", "IATA III", "IATA I", "IATA I", "IATA I", 
"IATA II", "IATA II", "IATA I", "IATA II", "IATA I", "IATA I", 
"IATA I", "IATA I", "IATA II", "IATA II", "IATA I", "IATA II", 
"IATA I", "IATA II", "IATA I", "IATA II", "IATA I", "IATA III", 
"IATA II", "IATA II", "IATA III", "IATA I", "IATA I", "IATA II", 
"IATA I", "IATA II", "IATA III", "IATA III", "IATA I", "IATA II", 
"IATA I", "IATA II", "IATA II", "IATA II", "IATA I"), Plant.Name = c("Witherhill Park", 
"Louisville", "Los Angeles", "Jamestown", "Hong Kong", "Oakville", 
"London", "Xiamen", "Phoenix", "Phoenix", "Wilson", "Dubai", 
"Wolverhampton", "Rome", "Prestwick", "Miramar", "Colorado", 
"Chula Vista", "Windsor Locks", "Marston", "Torino", "Puerto Rico", 
"LHotellier", "Monroe", "Maastricht", "Burnsville", "Vernon", 
"Rockford", "Singapore", "Turkey", "Toulouse", "FAST", "Peabody", 
"NURS", "Plymouth", "Foley", "Brugherio.Luserna", "Singapore", 
"Malaysia", "Vergennes", "Paris", "Brea", "St Ouen", "Dijon", 
"Marston Green", "Wichita"), OTD = c(0.988165680473373, 0.918974782968169, 
0.907429245283019, 0.84375, 0.822389666307858, 0.782608695652174, 
0.776832460732984, 0.765151515151515, 0.734375, 0.718238993710692, 
0.707799767171129, 0.690721649484536, 0.687732342007435, 0.675, 
0.663829787234043, 0.641509433962264, 0.636363636363636, 0.629955947136564, 
0.60202260559191, 0.601351351351351, 0.6, 0.59, 0.586206896551724, 
0.566975568660489, 0.558333333333333, 0.548062015503876, 0.534743202416918, 
0.521978021978022, 0.51063829787234, 0.5, 0.496240601503759, 
0.488888888888889, 0.485294117647059, 0.484848484848485, 0.470588235294118, 
0.448818897637795, 0.440677966101695, 0.436619718309859, 0.435672514619883, 
0.397752808988764, 0.396648044692737, 0.367647058823529, 0.322147651006711, 
0.304568527918782, 0.232876712328767, 0.07981220657277), Shipments = c(169, 
2419, 1696, 32, 929, 69, 1528, 132, 128, 795, 859, 97, 269, 40, 
236, 530, 22, 227, 1681, 149, 276, 100, 29, 1187, 600, 1290, 
331, 182, 611, 6, 133, 90, 272, 338, 51, 128, 118, 142, 344, 
445, 179, 68, 149, 197, 292, 213)), row.names = c(NA, -46L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = c("SBU", "Region"), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("SBU", 
"Region", "Plant.Name", "OTD", "Shipments"), indices = list(5L, 
    c(12L, 20L, 26L, 36L, 42L), c(17L, 35L), c(14L, 29L, 30L), 
    37L, c(9L, 15L, 21L, 23L, 27L, 33L), c(11L, 24L, 40L, 43L
    ), c(7L, 28L, 31L, 38L), c(13L, 18L, 32L), c(19L, 44L), c(3L, 
    8L, 16L), c(1L, 2L, 45L), 6L, c(0L, 4L), c(10L, 25L, 39L, 
    41L), c(22L, 34L)), group_sizes = c(1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L), biggest_group_size = 6L, labels = structure(list(
    SBU = c("APS", "APS", "ASG", "ASG", "ASG", "CS", "CS", "CS", 
    "ES", "ES", "INT", "LS", "LS", "LS", "SIS", "SIS"), Region = c("IATA I", 
    "IATA II", "IATA I", "IATA II", "IATA III", "IATA I", "IATA II", 
    "IATA III", "IATA I", "IATA II", "IATA I", "IATA I", "IATA II", 
    "IATA III", "IATA I", "IATA II")), row.names = c(NA, -16L
), class = "data.frame", vars = c("SBU", "Region"), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("SBU", 
"Region")))
```

Below is my code:

```
input1 <- "APS"
input2 <- NULL
input3 <- NULL

if (is.null(input1) & is.null(input2) & is.null(input3)) {SiteOTD$Colors <- "#003395"
} else if (!is.null(input1) & is.null(input2) & is.null(input3)) {SiteOTD$Colors <- ifelse(SiteOTD$SBU == input1,"#000000","#003395")}

highchart() %>%
  hc_yAxis_multiples(list(title = list(text = "%, OTD"),lineWidth = 0), list(title = list(text = "Qty, Volume"), opposite = TRUE)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(SiteOTD, "column", hcaes(x = Plant.Name, y = round(OTD,2)*100), name = "On Time Delivery", yAxis = 0, dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, fontSize = "0.5vh")) %>%
  hc_add_series(SiteOTD, "line", hcaes(x = Plant.Name, y = Shipments), name = "Volume", marker = "diamond", color = "#FF7900", yAxis = 1) %>%
  hc_xAxis(title = "Sites", categories = paste0(SiteOTD$Plant.Name,"-",SiteOTD$SBU), labels = list(step = 1, rotation = -60, style = list(fontSize = "1.0vh"))) %>%
  hc_tooltip(crosshairs = TRUE, shared = TRUE, headerFormat = "<b>{point.x}</b><br>") %>%
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(series = list(colorByPoint = TRUE, type = "column", colors = SiteOTD$Colors))
```

If you remove `hc_plotOptions`, the line series shows. If you keep it, `colorByPoint` works but the line series disappears.

Comment: I don't know much about R but maybe this demo in pure Highcharts (JS only) will help: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u9qpdw03/

Comment: It looks like they use {},{} to denote the two different series. I'm not sure how this converts to R though :/

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! I can put the `max` in the `hc_yAxis_multiples` and in `hc_plotOptions`, instead of using `series`, I use `column`.

```
highchart() %>%
            hc_yAxis_multiples(list(title = list(text = "%, OTD"),lineWidth = 0, labels = list(format = "{value}%"), max = 100), list(title = list(text = "Qty, Volume"), opposite = TRUE)) %>%
            hc_xAxis(title = "Sites", categories = paste0(SiteOTD$Plant.Name,"-",SiteOTD$SBU), labels = list(step = 1, rotation = -60, style = list(fontSize = "1.0vh"))) %>%
            hc_add_series(SiteOTD, "column", hcaes(x = Plant.Name, y = round(OTD,2)*100), name = "On Time Delivery", yAxis = 0) %>%
            hc_add_series(SiteOTD, "line", hcaes(x = Plant.Name, y = Shipments), name = "Volume", marker = "diamond", color = "#FF7900", yAxis = 1) %>%
            hc_tooltip(crosshairs = TRUE, headerFormat = "<b>{point.x}</b><br>") %>%
            hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>%
            hc_plotOptions(column = list(colorByPoint = TRUE, colors = SiteOTD$Colors))
```

This removed the functionality of `shared = TRUE` in `hc_tooltip` which is slightly annoying though.